# Best way to lock tokens for investors vesting period

Tags: tokens, erc-20, security

What would be the most convenient way for our team to lock tokens for a vesting period for a relatively large number of wallets? (30+)

We've considered team.finance as well as writing our own contract and UI.

Is there a 3rd option we are missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using [Sablier](https://sablier.com) (disclaimer: I'm a co-founder).

Sablier is a token streaming protocol that enables by-the-second payments. The way it works is that the sender deposits an amount of ERC-20 assets in a contract, which then progressively allocates the funds to the designated recipient.

The protocol has been running safely and reliably on Ethereum since December 2019. The median monthly TVL between 2021 and 2023 has been [$174M](https://defillama.com/protocol/sablier).

Links:

- App: https://pay.sablier.com
- Docs: https://docs.sablier.com
- Twitter: https://twitter.com/Sablier
- Discord: https://discord.gg/KXajCXC

Notable projects using Sablier include ShapeShift, Compound, Reflexer, Vita DAO, Aragon, Nouns DAO, and Maple Finance.

If you'd prefer not to waste any gas on Mainnet, rest assured that you can use the app on cheaper networks like Polygon. Also, if you'd like to use Sablier with a multisig, Sablier is natively integrated on [Safe](https://safe.global).

If you'd like a custom token logo listed in the UI, you can open a ticket [here](https://github.com/sablier-labs/community-token-list/issues/new/choose).

Comment: This looks like the service we are looking for, will check it out for sure.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Team Finance. Their vesting product is extremely bad.

- Smart contracts are closed source, so you can't prove the vesting schedule on the chain.
- Their user interface does not provide a display to prove the vesting schedule either.
- And when you want to cancel the vesting (their docs say you can), you realize there is no such functionality on GUI they provide.
- When you contact their support they dismiss you by saying "they will ask the team and get to you soon".

I used their service, and in the end, I lost my token contract and had to deploy another instance.

EDIT: It's been six months, and they still didn't "get to me". I already moved on and accepted the loss, but just so you know. They are terrible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a 3rd option we are missing?

[Superfluid provides linearly vesting tokens as a smart contract service](https://help.superfluid.finance/en/articles/6927461-set-up-vesting-schedules).