# how to code erc20token with minting function for specific amount for every specific interval of time..?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, erc-20, mint

say i have "Total_Supply=2750000000tokens",we need to "mint=2150000000tokens" for every day up to 360 days, like to mint 2100tokens for every half'n hour(30 min) totally(100800tokens for every day)

what are the functions i need to add into it??? i tried to create a uint time variable to keep count of time but it can't keep it up since the block.timestamp returns epoch(BIG seconds number) hence the "Outofmemory" error kicks in..

I'm using openzeppelin library to create ERC20 token like this:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

    import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelincontracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';


    contract MyToken is ERC20{
    
        address public admin;
        constructor() ERC20('MyToken','AHH'){
        
        //give name for token and symbol
            _mint(msg.sender,10000*10**18);
            //initial_token
            admin = msg.sender;
        }
        
        function mint(address to,uint amount) external{
            require(admin == msg.sender,"error only admin");
            _mint(to,amount);
        }
        function burn(uint amount) external{
            _burn(msg.sender,amount);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Why not mint it all at once and use [Sablier](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/98481/24693) for vesting? Sablier is the most popular protocol for vesting ERC-20 tokens. At the time of writing this comment, it has around [$1.4B](https://defillama.com/protocol/sablier-finance) in TVL.

Comment: the requirement for client is something like this and i've coded the a time based modifier to do this:
function mint(address to,uint amount) external{
            require(admin == msg.sender,"error only admin");
     require(block.timestamp>= 30min,"error");    
_mint(to,amount);
but the client want to mint different amount through out a day.....and he wants to automate that...

Comment: Minting is unnecessary. Tell your client to consider Sablier for vesting purposes. (S)He'd be in good hands.