# How to Implement a Time-Locked Crowd sale with Multiple Vesting Schedule and Token Distribution for an ERC20 token PreICO, ICO & PostICO stages

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, crowdsale, timelock

I am working on a ERC20 token crowd sale project. The token distribution and vesting schedule is a little bit complicated.
So Here is the scenario:

Total Supply: 1,000,000,000

Token Distribution:

- Public Sale: 1.5%
- Private Investor: 7%
- Seed Investor: 7%
- Equity Seed Investor: 5.3%
- Marketing: 1%
- Market Making: 3%
- Treasury: 16.9%
- Team and Advisors: 23.3%
- Reward Pools & Tokens: 35%

One thing to point our is that the token distribution is done gradually, meaning every month, a percentage of the total supply is released. For example at launch, 6% of the total supply is released and distributed. The next month, 7% is distributed, etc. until 100% of the total supply has been distributed. Each category of token holder has a vesting schedule.

The vesting schedule looks something like this:

[image]

Below is a more detailed breakdown by month

[image]

I have also watched the tutorial by Gregory from DApp University on [Token Vesting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxzJiGPyyLw&t=811s) and read bunch of other articles on the topic. My question is this:

Given that I need to whitelist every single token holder depending on their class (Founder, investor, public sale, etc.), is it a good idea to create 8 separate crowd sale contracts, given that vesting schedules are different and percentages are also different from a founding team to a private investor. And then have one central crowd sale that will have some sort of ownership over the other crowd sales.
In case I decide to go with one crowd sale to handle everything how do I whitelist each category of token holder separately?

I am very confused as to how to write the crowd sale for this scenario and I need help on this one.
Please let me know if I should clarify something. I am more than happy to share more info about my struggles.

Amicably,

Comment: Good question, well written. I don't think I can help you with everything. But I am positive you can Whitelist 8 different categories in the same contract (If you choose to do so). Doing it in 8 separate contracts is an option too, and it might be a "cleaner" and more agile way to go.

Comment: Hi @Sky. Thanks for your comment. I am having a hard time envisioning everything together. So if I decide to go with 8 contracts, The sole purpose of those contracts would be to add, whitelist token holders and keep track of them. So Should I for instance follow the process outlined in Gregory's video for one category of token holder and then duplicate it for other categories?

Also, could you please share how you would go about whitelisting 8 different cats in the same SC? And how would you represent all those various vesting schedules (Monthly, etc.). Thanks for letting me bombard you :)

Comment: Related: a popular vesting solution in Ethereum is [Sablier](https://sablier.finance). See [this conversation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/98477/24693). Disclaimer: I'm the founder.

Comment: Not a problem AllJs. But I think it would be best if we arranged a meeting and discuss this because there is so much to go over there. And I am in the middle of refactoring smartContracts for my employer. So I would only be available tomorrow after 16:00 CET. (We could use discord or google meetings) 

However, yes, you could indeed whitelist 8 separate classes, but depending on other functions needed to support the functionality of those classes, the contract itself might be too large to deploy.

Comment: Plus, it's easier to update/fix any issues or upgrade functionality if they are spread over a multitude of contracts.

Comment: Maybe @PaulRazvanBerg here would be willing to aid you too, as it would be in his interest for you to use his pre-made solution.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg thanks for your comment. Please checkout the updated question with a detail breakdown by month of cliff and vesting periods. I looked at Sablier and I am pretty new to it. So I didn't know where to start, but I do more research on it. Thanks for sharing. That's caring.

Comment: @Sky my discord is watat83#1061. Also checkout my question(Update)