# How to claim tokens from vesting contract?

Tags: gnosis-safe

we have added a Gnosis safe address to a vesting contract. What's the best way for the multisig to claim those tokens? Can a member of the multisig claim via a dapp or does it need to be called through the dashboard somehow?

Comment: If you were to use [Sablier](https://sablier.finance) for vesting purposes, you would be able to claim those tokens via our easy-to-use Gnosis Safe plugin. See my answer here: [Best way to lock tokens for investors vesting period](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98477/best-way-to-lock-tokens-for-investors-vesting-period/98481#98481). Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of Sablier.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods

### Method 1: Use wallet connect

If there is a dApp a regular account can use to claim the vested tokens, you can connect via Wallet Connect. On the dApp where you would usually connect with metamask, there may be options to select Wallet connect, you will get a QR code like this

[image: Wallet Connect Modlal]

Click copy to the clipboard at the bottom, then head back over to your safe and under apps find wallet connect and paste in the link

when you go back to the dapp and follow the usual claim flow. Back in your safe, you can approve the transaction

### Method 2: Transaction Builder

and this is the most reliable method, you need to find the contract address for the vesting contract. Under Apps in your safe, there is an app called transaction builder. paste in the contract address and if the contract is verified (which it should be), you find the function that says claim and call it. If you can't read the contract yourself, then you should ask the team for the correct function to call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should work the same way as with any other wallet - you need to create a claiming transaction, and all owners of the multisig should approve it.