# Unable to claim vesting from team finance

Tags: gnosis-safe

We've been trying for a few days to execute the claim function of a vesting that we made in our project.

We identified that we vested from two wallets that are actually contracts linked to Gnosis Safe.

The two wallets we need to receive from the claim are the following:

1. 0x056f3E1B30797a122447581d0F34CD69E9A26690
2. 0x5C60B40A7735B1F310b8F35D95E3d6Cb25F7ffB2

The team finance vesting contract is this:
0xdbd8e899c2b2aa8c1da54c824fea17d58e082465

As you know, we had difficulty executing this claim through the team finance website. You instructed us to try to execute the claim function directly from the contract. And we tried to do that for the following services: Laika and Remix. However, we were not successful.

Laika: We were not successful because this service has only metamask integration and has no connection to wallet connect.

Remix: In the case of Remix, it was giving an error in the wallet connect function. We suspect that this error is due to the fact that the wallets are actually contracts and the Remix service was unable to interpret this.

So how can we claim the Team Finance contract for our Gnosis Safe contracts?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but in the future you might find it easier to run your vesting through [Sablier](https://sablier.finance). See this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98477/best-way-to-lock-tokens-for-investors-vesting-period/98481?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C0.0000#98481) as well.

Comment: Don't use Team Finance: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/140076/18576